# Can I store reference on key object from WeakMap value object without preventing GC?

Tags: javascript, reference, garbage-collection, weak, weakmap

Since GC detects isolated islands of object graph to find candidates for removal from memory and WeakMap does not break island boundaries with it's weak references `WeakMap -> KeyObject` then it would make sense for this reference `WeakMap -> Value -> KeyObject` to also not break island boundaries with weak `WeakMap -> Value` reference, while `Value -> KeyObject` reference is obviously strong.

Example:

```
let o = {test:1};
let map = new WeakMap();
map.set(o, {strongRef: o});
o = null; // clear last reference on {test:1}
// will {test:1} be GCed after this ?
```

Comment: Please leave a comment if you think it's not a dupe and I'll reopen it.

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32687100/251311

Comment: The key to understanding mentioned duplicate question is to realize that  "circular" means half of circular. Full circular would be references map->Value->KeyObject->map, but "circular" is only map->Value->KeyObject.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Would a "circular" reference be treated as "reachability" for a WeakMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687100/would-a-circular-reference-be-treated-as-reachability-for-a-weakmap)