# Does cross-referencing in WeakMap prevent garbage collection?

Tags: javascript, weak-references, weakmap

I'm extending this question: [Would a "circular" reference be treated as "reachability" for a WeakMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687100/would-a-circular-reference-be-treated-as-reachability-for-a-weakmap)

If I have 2 WeakMaps that have entries whose values cross references the keys, would this prevent garbage collection or not?

Example:

```
    let obj1 = {}, obj2 = {}
    obj1.ref = obj2
    obj2.ref = obj1

    const map1 = new WeakMap([[obj2, obj2]])
    const map2 = new WeakMap([[obj1, obj1]])

    obj1 = obj2 = null

    // obj1, obj2 garbage collected?
```

Answer in this question assume but doesn't confirm: [Can a bi-directional WeakMap lead to a memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65067147/can-a-bi-directional-weakmap-lead-to-a-memory-leak)

Comment: I think this should work (objects should be garbage collected) as they are not strongly reachable from any GC root.

Comment: No, this does not prevent garbage collection. Neither `obj1` nor `obj2` are kept alive by anything.